# Is it possible to use boolean in an animationDrawable in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button, boolean, animationdrawable

I have a project where i have two images in loop in a AnimationDrawable, and i would like to use a single button that play a specific sound for the image that is on screen, for example: when image 1 is on screen when button press audio A plays, when image 2 is on screen on button press audio B play.
I was thinking on use a boolean to identify the image that is on screen, but i don't know if it is possible or if there is a better way to do it. Could someone help me?

For now it didn't work for:

---

```
    public void onClick(View imagem) {

          if (snAnimacao.equals(R.drawable.1))
              A.start();
          else {
                 B.start();
          }
        }
```